# How to convert json Object to json Array?

Tags: php, json

Im new to Json and I encountered a problem that need to be fix so that I can continue with my project.. Hope you will help me guys..

This is my Json Object response

```
{
 "error":false,
 "sl_summ":
    {
        "sl_desc":"PA : Savings Account",
        "tr_date":"2015-08-17",
        "actual_balance":"483.67",
        "available_balance":"483.67"
    }
}

{
  "error":false,
  "sl_summ":
    {
        "sl_desc":"PA : Savings - Cash Bond",
        "tr_date":"2015-08-28",
        "actual_balance":"10129.43",
        "available_balance":"10129.43"
    }
}
```

and I want to convert my following Json Object (above) to this Json array format (below)

```
{
  "error":false,
   "sl_summ":
    [{
        "sl_desc":"PA : Savings Account",
        "tr_date":"2015-08-17",
        "actual_balance":"483.67",
        "available_balance":"483.67"
    },
    {
        "sl_desc":"PA : Savings - Cash Bond",
        "tr_date":"2015-08-28",
        "actual_balance":"10129.43",
        "available_balance":"10129.43"
    }]
}
```

this is my code

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($user_sldtl); $i++){
   $sl_response["error"] = FALSE;
   //$sl_response["sl_summ"]["sl_brcode"] = $user_sldtl[$i][0];
   //$sl_response["sl_summ"]["sl_memid"] = $user_sldtl[$i][3];
   $sl_response["sl_summ"]["sl_desc"] = $user_sldtl[$i][7];
   $sl_response["sl_summ"]["tr_date"] = $user_sldtl[$i][10];
   $sl_response["sl_summ"]["actual_balance"] = $user_sldtl[$i][14];
   $sl_response["sl_summ"]["available_balance"] = $user_sldtl[$i][14];
   json_encode($sl_response);
   //echo json_encode($sl_response, true);
}
```

Comment: You should first create your object outside the loop, then inside the loop you should **push** your data to the `sl_summ` array using eg. `array_push`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following codes:

```
<?php

$sl_response = array();
$sl_response["error"] = FALSE;
$sl_response["sl_summ"] = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($user_sldtl); $i++){
    $item = array();
    //$item["sl_brcode"] = $user_sldtl[$i][0];
    //$item["sl_memid"] = $user_sldtl[$i][3];
    $item["sl_desc"] = $user_sldtl[$i][7];
    $item["tr_date"] = $user_sldtl[$i][10];
    $item["actual_balance"] = $user_sldtl[$i][14];
    $item["available_balance"] = $user_sldtl[$i][14];

    $sl_response["sl_summ"][] = $item;
}
//json_encode($sl_response);
echo json_encode($sl_response, true);
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked, please accept this answer. @John

Comment: It added `"error": false` before `"sl_summ"`. What's your output? @John

Comment: its okie now sir @Mohammad Hamedani.  I was not able to put the code $sl_response["error"] = FALSE;

Comment: sir do you know how can I fetch the json value then store it to my android sqlite?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know android and sqlite. You can ask a new question and android man answer it. @John

Comment: sir can you answer this question sir? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938882/how-to-have-this-kind-of-json-response-formatting